# Decode JSON with class type as a parameter

Tags: kotlin

I am using the `kotlinx.serialization` package and would like to decode the json string `jstr` into the type passed as a parameter `targetClass` to a member function `toObject` of a class something like this

```
fun <T : Any> toObject(targetClass: KClass<T>): T {
    return when (targetClass) {
        TargetClass::class,
        ->
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            Json.decodeFromString<targetClass>(Json.encodeToString(jstr)) as T
        else -> throw Exception("Class type required")
    }
}
```

But it doesn't allow me to use the `targetClass` the way i am using, and I don't know how to set the return type for such a function.

I am new to kotlin, please help me make sense out of this.

Comment: Why do you need this function? Why not use `Json.decodeFromString<TheType>(jsonStr)` directly?

Comment: @Slaw So this function is inside a layer of abstraction. The `jstr` is a class variable and the type of json that it stores will be passed to this function

Comment: Is `jstr` already a String? If so, why are you trying to call `encodeToString` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using KClass

If you must work with `KClass`, then I believe you have to "manually" specify the `KSerializer` associated with the class.

### Obtaining Serializer

Obtaining the serializer involves using one of the non-inline [`serializer`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/serializer.html) functions. Here are some examples for getting compiler-generated serializers.

#### Example 1

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
val serializer: KSerializer<Any?> = serializer(targetClass, emptyList(), false)
```

#### Example 2

```kotlin
// import kotlin.reflect.full.createType
val serializer: KSerializer<Any?> = serializer(targetClass.createType())
```

This requires the `kotlin-reflect` library and thus will only work with Kotlin/JVM.

#### Example 3

```kotlin
val serializer: KSerializer<Any> = serializer(targetClass.java)
```

This will only work with Kotlin/JVM.

### Decoding

Once you have the `KSerializer` you can simply pass it to the `decodeFromString` function.

```kotlin
// where 'jsonString' comes from the enclosing scope
fun <T : Any> toObject(targetClass: KClass<T>): T {
    val serializer = ...
    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    return Json.decodeFromString(serializer, jsonString) as T
}
```

---

## Using KType

You may want to consider changing your function to accept a `KType` instead of a `KClass`.

```kotlin
// where 'jsonString' comes from the enclosing scope
fun <T : Any> toObject(targetType: KType): T {
    val serializer = serializer(targetType)
    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    return Json.decodeFromString(serializer, jsonString) as T
}
```

However, since `KType` is not generic there are at least two downsides.

1. No way to "force" the `KType` argument and `T` to represent the same type.
2. The `T` will no longer be inferable from the function argument.

The typical way to obtain a `KType` instance is via the `typeOf` function. Calling this version of `toObject` might look like:

```kotlin
val obj: Foo = toObject(typeOf<Foo>())
```

#### Reified type parameter

Of course, at that point it may make more sense to simply use an inline function with a reified type parameter.

```kotlin
// where 'jsonString' comes from the enclosing scope
inline fun <reified T : Any> toObject(): T {
    return Json.decodeFromString(jsonString)
}
```

```kotlin
val obj = toObject<Foo>()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to "catch" generic type param by using inline fun with reified generic param

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> toObject(): T =
        Json.decodeFromString<T>(Json.encodeToString(jstr))
```